# Python code works outside function, but doesn't work inside function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with some data, and just writing lines in sequence works fine and gives me the results I want (to extract a row of data from the date from the dataframe 'restaurant'):

```
orders = restaurant[(restaurant.index == date)]
```

However, when I put this into a function, it no longer is able to look it up by date, and instead just gives me a blank data frame:

```
def datesearch(date)   
    orders = restaurant[(restaurant.index == date)]
    return orders
```

I can't seem to figure out why it's fine outside the function, but for some reason, it can't search by the date when I put it in a function.

Comment: Are you passing the date to the function?

Comment: I'm very sorry, but what does that mean? Do I need to write date = date into my function first?

Comment: You'd call datesearch as `datesearch(date)`. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No - I don't get an error. Instead, I get a blank dataframe. It seems like my function is unable to locate the "date" row.

Comment: Hm, okay. Are you catching the return value from the function? In other words, `orders = datesearch(date)`?

Comment: Yep - for instance, if I put orders = datesearch(2001), orders comes out as a blank dataframe with only the index. However, if I pass 2001 through orders = restaurant[(restaurant.index == date)], I get what I want (a dataframe with the orders from 2001)

Comment: oh! is restaurant a global variable? I think I have an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `restaurant` is a global variable, so it might not be using the correct data. Try this:

```
def datesearch(date) 
    global restaurant  
    orders = restaurant[(restaurant.index == date)]
    return orders
```

Comment: I don't understand how this could possibly solve the problem, since you only need to declare a name global if you are modifying it.